# Color Guessing Game returns "Wrong" even when when i pick correct color

Tags: javascript

Trying to make Color Guessing game using JS.Console doesn't show me any errors, but it alerts me "Wrong!" even when I pick a correct number,when it needs to alert "Correct!"...I've been trying to solve this problem for about three hours!

If I remove `else{ alert ("Wrong!") }` and then click on a color there is no callback at all.Also,if I type in console `square[i].style.background` it returns me

```
undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
var colors = [ 
     "rgb(255,0,0)",
     "rgb(255,255,0)",
     "rgb(0,255,0)",
     "rgb(0,255,255)",
     "rgb(0,0,225)",
     "rgb(255,0,255)"
    ]
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    var pickedColor = colors [3];
    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay"); 
     colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    for(var i = 0; i <squares.length;i++){ 
        // add initial colors to squares
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
        // add click listeners to squares
        squares[i].addEventListener ("click",function() {
        // grab color of clicked square
        var clickedColor = this.style.background;
        // compare color to pickedColor
        if(clickedColor === pickedColor){ 
            alert("Correct!");
        } else {
            alert("Wrong!")
        }
        });
     }
```

And here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
</head>
<body> 
<h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>

   <div id="container">
     <div class= "square"></div>
     <div class= "square"></div>
     <div class= "square"></div>
     <div class= "square"></div>
     <div class= "square"></div>
     <div class= "square"></div>
   </div>  

     <script src="colorGame.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through it with a debugger and inspect the values?

Comment: It would be nice to see the HTML code as well.

Comment: Seems that `style.background` gives more than just the color. https://jsfiddle.net/7eu6Lk4g/ (At least it does in Firefox)

Comment: Please create a JsFiddle or Code snippet to reproduce the error

Comment: Just do what litelite suggested. That will help you the most with any future code projects: learn to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You used `style.background`. What you should use is `style.backgroundColor`

The `style.background` property contains:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

Comment: Yes sorry `backgroundColor` is right. Im sorry, fixed it

Comment: `background-color` is not `Basicly stuff for setting an Image as a background.`

Comment: Well i didnt say that. The context was `style.background` :P But last sentence was useless anyways.

Comment: This isn't the problem though. In Chrome, or at least on my Chrome, style.background and style.backgroundColor both return 'rgb(xxx, xxx, xxx)' in this case (note the spaces after each comma), leading me to believe that the results are browser specific. I think it would be better to not rely on the background property at all as the browser can re-format the input.

Comment: When I write  'code' squares[i].style.background 'code' or 'code' squares[i].style.backgroundColor 'code' it return me "undefined"

Comment: Make sure to set the style property like this  : `squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];`

Answer (score 0):

The format that `this.style.background` gives is slightly different from what's in your array in that it has spaces after each comma (in Chrome). It's an easy fix.

I'd like to argue that you could avoid this problem (and browser specific issues) by storing the color on the element as a class (or some other attribute), then just checking if that attribute is the same. That way your input won't get modified by the browser.

```js
var colors = [ 
     "rgb(255,0,0)",
     "rgb(255,255,0)",
     "rgb(0,255,0)",
     "rgb(0,255,255)",
     "rgb(0,0,225)",
     "rgb(255,0,255)"
    ]
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    var pickedColor = colors [3];
    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay"); 
     colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    for(var i = 0; i <squares.length;i++){ 
        // add initial colors to squares
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
        // add as class
        squares[i].classList.add(colors[i]);
        // add click listeners to squares
        squares[i].addEventListener ("click",function() {
          // compare color to pickedColor
          if(this.classList.contains(pickedColor)){ 
              alert("Correct!");
          } else {
              alert("Wrong!")
          }
        });
     }
```

```css
.square{
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" ></div>
<div class="square" ></div>
<div class="square" ></div>
<div class="square" ></div>
<div class="square" ></div>
<div class="square" ></div>
<div id="colorDisplay" />
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I updated the answer and it should work on any browser that supports `element#classList`